# . (dot) in argparse argument and variable name

Tags: python, syntax, argparse

Is it possible to have an argument parser like this?

```
import argparse
parser.add_argument('query2target.bam', help='A bam file containing contigs from \'query\' aligned to contigs in \'target\'')
args = parser.parse_args()
q2t = args.query2target.bam
```

I want the parser name to be 'query2target.bam' but then when I go to name a variable after it, `q2t = args.query2target.bam` it thinks that the extension is a function method. How do I solve this without renaming the argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind my previous answer. There actually is a clean solution to this problem; writing a [custom action](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#action) for the `ArgumentParser`:

```
import argparse

class Q2TAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string):
        self.query2target = values

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
q2taction = parser.add_argument("query2target.bam", action=Q2TAction)
parser.parse_args()

print(q2taction.query2target)
```

Comment: I would have been ok with 'abusing' `getattr`, but cleaner is always better. This is a much nicer solution, thanks larsmans.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `dest` parameter.

```
parser.add_argument('query2target.bam', dest='query2target', help="...")
args = parser.parse_args()
q2t = args.query2target
```

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 2):

Python objects actually can have attributes with names containing dots. You can see them printing the `__dict__` attribute of your `args` variable which would seem like:

```
>>> print args.__dict__
{'query2target.bam': 'your-argument-value'}
```

You can easily extract this attribute's value using `getattr()` built-in function:

```
q2t = getattr(args, 'query2target.bam')
```

But still it's probably better to stick with the convention.

Comment: Cool this is what I wanted. I know I should stick to convention, but I find it easier for everybody to understand that the file must be in a specific format if you can see the 'dot'. People tend to neglect written instructions but the .extension is universal and subconsciously your brain registers it better IMO.

Comment: This is horrible. @Dan: if you really want a dot in the name, then use a `dict` instead of abusing `getattr`.

Comment: @larsmans, agree - not pretty - but "without renaming the argument". Also notice that he can only use what API has provided.

Comment: @MikołajSiedlarek: yes, but upon studying this API, I found that there actually is a clean (though lengthy) way of doing this cleanly; see my answer.